# C losing pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

when I insert a new struct A with the '1' command (so I already have one or more struct A linked to one or more struct S), i lose the link of the previous struct A to their struct S.
For exaple:

> command 1 and then command 3 : 2014 and command 4
>
> Output:
>
> year:2014
>
> matricola:1
>
> now command 1 and then command 3 : 2015 and command 4
>
> Output:
>
> year:2015
>
> matricola:2
>
> year:2014
>
> no S struct

I hope that the example will be helpful
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S
{
    int matr;
    struct S* next;
};
struct A
{
    int year;
    struct A *nextA;
    struct S *nextS;
};
int years = 2013;
int matricola=0;
void insA(struct A**T);
void printA(struct A*T);
void insS(struct A **T);
void printS(struct A *T);

int main()
{
    struct A *T=NULL;
    int cmd,sc=0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n command:");
        sc=scanf("%d",&cmd);
        while(sc==0)
        {
            printf("\nerror:");
            fflush(stdin);
            sc=scanf("%d",&cmd);
        }
        if(cmd==1)
        {
            insA(&T);
        }
        if(cmd==2)
        {
            printA(T);
        }
        if(cmd==3)
        {
            insS(&T);
        }
        if(cmd==4)
        {
            printS(T);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void insA(struct A**T)
{
    struct A *new_p=(struct A*)malloc(sizeof(struct A));
    if(new_p==NULL)
    {
        printf("Errore");
        exit(0);
    }
    years++;
    new_p->nextA=NULL;
    new_p->nextS=NULL;

    if((*T)==NULL)
    {
        (*T)=new_p;
    }
    else
    {
        new_p->nextA=(*T);
        (*T)=new_p;
    }
    new_p->year=years;
}
void printA(struct A *T)
{
    struct A *tmp=T;
    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%d",tmp->year);
        tmp=tmp->nextA;
    }
    return;
}
void insS(struct A **T)
{
    int search,sc=0;
    struct S* new_p=(struct S*)malloc(sizeof(struct S));
    if(new_p==NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
        exit(0);
    }
    new_p->next=NULL;

    printf("\nyear in which to insert:");
    sc=scanf("%4d",&search);
    while(sc==0 || search > years || search <= 2013)
    {
        printf("\nerror:");
        fflush(stdin);
        sc=scanf("%4d",&search);
    }

    struct A*tmp=*T;
    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        if(tmp->year==search)
        {
            matricola++;
            if(tmp->nextS==NULL)
            {
                tmp->nextS=new_p;
            }
            else
            {
                new_p->next=tmp->nextS;
                tmp->nextS=new_p;
            }
        }
        tmp=tmp->nextA;
    }
    new_p->matr=matricola;
    return;
}
void printS(struct A *T)
{
    struct A *tmp=T;
    struct S *s=tmp->nextS;
    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nyear:%d",tmp->year);
        if(s==NULL)
        {
            printf("\nno S struct");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            while(s!=NULL)
            {
                printf("\nmatricola:%d",s->matr);
                s=s->next;
            }
        }
        tmp=tmp->nextA;
    }
}
```

And this is my first post so I apologize for any errors .

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if it were properly indented. Do you have a source formatter that can do it for you?

Comment: It would be nice if you had a `if (cmd == 5) exit(1);` with the proper clean up of cource.

Comment: Using `fflush(stdin)` is not recommended, it is intended to be used with stdout.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: You should be clear on which language you are coding in. Is it C or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling to understand what you want to do I figured out your problem, you have to change your printS function.

```
void printS(struct A *T) {
    struct A *tmp=T;
    truct S *s = tmp->nextS;

    while(tmp != NULL) {
        printf("\nyear:%d", tmp->year);

        if(s == NULL) {
            printf("\nno S struct");
            return ;
        } else {
            while(s != NULL) {
                printf("\nmatricola:%d",s->matr);
                s = s->next;
            }
        }
        tmp = tmp->nextA;
    }
}
```

Like this.

```
void printS(struct A *T) {
    struct A *tmp=T;

    while(tmp != NULL) {
        struct S *s = tmp->nextS;
        printf("\nyear:%d", tmp->year);

        if(s == NULL) {
            printf("\nno S struct");
            return ;
        } else {
            while(s != NULL) {
                printf("\nmatricola:%d",s->matr);
                s = s->next;
            }
        }
        tmp = tmp->nextA;
    }
}
```

Because the `struct S *s = tmp->nextS;` have to be updated to the actual struct A in which you are, so it have to be inside the while loop, if you leave `struct S *s = tmp->nextS;` outside the while loop you will try to print the list of structs S that starts from your first struct A, and not the entire list of structs S starts from each struct A.

**Note:** As I said, try to avoid `fflush(stdin);` because if the argument don't point to an output stream the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now.
You are right, I should clarify the purpose of the program.